# UITableView delete/add row causes CoreData: Serious Application Error if another object has been selected in the MasterView of a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, core-data

**Update 18/3 #2. I've started counting beginUpdates and EndUpdates to make sure they're even. Right before there's an exception, they get out of sync. Not sure why though.**

**UPDATE 18/3: I think I've found the problem**, but I'm not sure if I know how to fix it. After experimenting for a couple hours, I found I could only crash the app when I had selected more than one item in the master tableview of the svc during that session. 
When another item is selected in the master tableview, the detail table view gets a new object set and refreshtables is called EVEN IF it's halfway through an update/move/delete/insert cycle. Hence the problem; I think it has instructions to update the old story object even though a new story object has been set on the detailviewcontroller.

**How can I get the animation/coredata/tableview updates to be processed completely before a new story is set in the detail view? I save changes to the managedObjectContext when setEditting == NO. I'm guessing I need to make a custom setStory setter that processes all the updates to the UITableView/CoreData set before accepting the new object?**

This code gets called on the master tableview controller of the svc in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[detailViewController setStory:storySet]; //where storySet is the new story object
[detailViewController refreshTables];
```

I have intermittent errors on attempting to delete the row where action won't animate and the application essentially hangs with the following error (the row is deleted from the CoreData set though). This happens if I have chosen more than one row from the master tableview controller in the svc in one session.

After some googling I thought it might be a problem with **(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)** which is called after an update to animate the changes the user has made.

How can I fix these intermittent bugs?

- 16/3I've tried to really simplify my code. I've removed all calls to the Managed Object Context and put them in setEditing, removed superfluous [self.tableview reloadData] and [self.tableview setneedsdisplay] and invalidated the 'reordering' bool completely (it's still in the code, but it's always set to NO, so it makes no difference). The UITableView is more stable then ever, but I still manage to get intermittent errors on delete (and occasionally on add) - it seems to take a while to crash but it still will.**
- 15/3: I think that it has something to do with the CoreData / UITableView being out of sync - CoreData thinks it has less or more than the UITableView
- There's no problem with the CoreData set, it's just the animation/UI side of things (things get removed)
- It's intermittent, only on some deletes
- After some help from *railwayparade* I implemented NSFetchedResultsChangeMove in didChangeObject: which fixed the moving error but not the delete errors.

Can anyone see anything I've missed or that I can check? Happy to give more information if that helps solve the problem.

Apologies for the obscene amount of code posted here.

The Error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 3 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo
>   (null)

```
//
//  MakeSentenceTableViewController.h
//  StoryBot
//
//  Created by Glen Storey on 25/10/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Glen Storey. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddStoryItem.h"
#import "Story.h"
#import "Sentence.h"


@interface MakeSentenceTableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, AddStoryItemDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    NSManagedObjectContext      *managedObjectContext;  
    NSFetchedResultsController  *fetchedResultsController;
    UIPopoverController         *popoverController;
    UIBarButtonItem             *playButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem             *addButtonItem;

    BOOL                        reordering;
    BOOL                        insert;
    BOOL                        delete;
    BOOL                        move;

    int                         beginUpdatesCount;
    int                         endUpdatesCount;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain)   Story *story;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem *playButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem;
@property BOOL reordering,  insert,  delete,  move;

-(IBAction)createStoryModal:(id)sender;
-(void)refreshTables;
-(IBAction)pushShare:(id)sender;


@end


//
//  MakeSentenceTableViewController.m
//  
//
//  Created by Glen Storey on 25/10/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Glen Storey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MakeSentenceTableViewController.h"
#import "ShareViewController.h"
#import "StoryBotAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MakeSentenceTableViewController
@synthesize story, managedObjectContext, addButtonItem, playButtonItem, reordering, insert, delete, move;

-(void)addStoryItemAction:(NSString*)text order:(NSNumber*)order image:(NSString*)image thumb:(NSString*)thumb{

    NSLog(@"Text: %@, Order: %@, Image: %@.", text, order, image);
    NSLog(@"beginUpdatesCount: %d vs. endUpdatescount: %d", beginUpdatesCount, endUpdatesCount);

    NSSet *sentences = [story sentences];
    NSNumber *maxOrder = [sentences valueForKeyPath:@"@max.order"];
    NSLog(@"maxOrder: %@", maxOrder);

    if(maxOrder == 0){

        maxOrder = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 0];
    }

    //make a new sentence!
    Sentence *sentence = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sentence" 
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [sentence setText: text];
    [sentence setImage: image];
    [sentence setThumb: thumb];
    [sentence setBelongsTo: story];
    if([maxOrder intValue] >= 1 ){
            [sentence setOrder: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:[maxOrder intValue]+1]]; 
    }else{
            [sentence setOrder: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1]];
    }
    NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:sentences];
    [mutableSet addObject:sentence];

    //NSLog(@"sentences before setWithSet %@", mutableSet);

    sentences = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet: mutableSet];

    //NSLog(@"sentences after setWithSet %@", sentences); 

    [story setSentences:sentences];

    //NSError *error;  

    //BOOL isSaved = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    //NSLog(@"isSaved? %@", (isSaved ? @"YES" :@"NO ") );

    //if (!isSaved) {
        //NSLog(@"%@:%s Error saving context: %@", [self class], _cmd, [error localizedDescription]);
        //Don't worry about this warning - just rem it out when finished (just a log)
      //  return;
    //} 

    [sentences release];
    [mutableSet release];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    //[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  



}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)name bundle:(NSBundle*)bundle;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:name bundle:bundle];

    if (self) {

        self.title = @"My Stories";

        addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                                       target:self
                                                                                       action:@selector(createStoryModal:)];

        playButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay 
                                                                                        target:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(pushShare:)];
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { 
            [addButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
            [playButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
        }


        NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 addButtonItem,
                                 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                               target:nil
                                                                               action:nil],
                                 playButtonItem,
                                 nil];

        [toolbarItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
        self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;  

        //NSLog(@"self: %@ self.toolbarItems: %@", self, self.toolbarItems);


        //Do I need to release UIBarButtonItems? 

        NSLog(@"initWithNibName:");
    }



    return self;
}

-(void)refreshTables{

    //use this to refresh for new table content. Also calls self.tableview reloadData so you don't need to call it afterward. 

    NSLog(@"===================================refreshTables");
    NSLog(@"story object %@", story);

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"managedObjectContext == nil");
        managedObjectContext = [(StoryBotAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"managedObjectContext != nil");
    }



    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sentence" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    //sorting stuff:
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending: YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSPredicate *predicateTitle = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsTo=%@",story];
    [request setPredicate :predicateTitle];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[story creationDate]];

    NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:dateString];

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [request release];

    NSError *error;
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"My Story";

    NSLog(@"Passed Story Object: %@", story);
    //NSLog(@"managedObjectContext: %@", managedObjectContext); 
    //Need a predicate for belongsTo here.

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 50;

    if(story != NULL){
        if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
        { 
            NSLog(@"managedObjectContext == nil");
            managedObjectContext = [(StoryBotAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"managedObjectContext != nil");
        }



        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sentence" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];

        //sorting stuff:
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending: YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [sortDescriptors release];
        [sortDescriptor release];

        NSPredicate *predicateTitle = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsTo=%@",story];
        [request setPredicate :predicateTitle];



        fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                    initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        [request release];

        NSError *error;
        [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];




    }



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *sections = [fetchedResultsController sections];
    NSInteger count = 0;

    if ([sections count]){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
        count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
    NSLog(@"# of rows in section %d", count);
    return count;

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    Sentence *sentenceAtCell = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //NSLog(@"sentenceAtCell: %@", sentenceAtCell);

    cell.textLabel.text = [sentenceAtCell text];



    NSArray *paths       = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *uniquePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sentenceAtCell thumb]];


    // This should crop it as you want - you've just got to create cropRect.

    UIImage *largeImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 50); 


    /*if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2) {
            // running an iPhone 4 or equiv. res device.
            cropRect = CGRectMake(15, 14, 100, 75); 
        }
    }*/


    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);



    //NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", indexPath);

    return cell;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSLog(@"Delete row");
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


        //  1. Look at the sentence we're about to delete.
        Sentence *sentenceRetire =      [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //  2. Does it have an order of 0? 
        NSLog(@"=================== sentenceRetire: %@", sentenceRetire);


        if([[sentenceRetire order] intValue] == 0){
                //      YES: Is there another sentence in this story?
                Story *storyRetire                      = [sentenceRetire belongsTo];
                NSSet *sentencesInRetiredSentenceSet    = [storyRetire sentences];


                if ([sentencesInRetiredSentenceSet count] > 1){
                    //          YES:    Set the sentence with the smallest order to an order of 0   
                    //                  then delete the sentence + files

                    NSPredicate *predicateTitle             = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order>0"];
                    NSSet *sentencesWithPotentialToBeTitle  = [sentencesInRetiredSentenceSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicateTitle];
                    NSNumber *minOrder                      = [sentencesWithPotentialToBeTitle valueForKeyPath:@"@min.order"];  

                    NSPredicate *predicateOrder             = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order=%d",[minOrder intValue]];
                    NSSet *sentenceWithPotentialToBeTitle   = [sentencesWithPotentialToBeTitle filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicateOrder];   

                    //note the sentence (singular) not sentences. This is the sentence who's order needs to be updated.     
                    NSLog(@"setenceWithPotentialToBeTitle (check order isn't null on crash): %@", sentenceWithPotentialToBeTitle);  
                    Sentence *sentenceToPromote = [sentenceWithPotentialToBeTitle anyObject];

                    //now we know which sentence to promote we can delete the sentence & Files.     
                    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

                    NSString *imageTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString*)[sentenceRetire image]];
                    NSString *thumbTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sentenceRetire thumb]];

                    NSLog(@"About to delete these files: %@, %@", imageTrash, thumbTrash);

                    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:imageTrash error:NULL];
                    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:thumbTrash error:NULL];

                    //and promote the new title.    
                    [sentenceToPromote setOrder:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0]];



                }else{
                    //          NO:     We're deleting this story
                    //                  Delete the files! 
                    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:storyRetire]; 
                    NSString *imageTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString*)[sentenceRetire image]];
                    NSString *thumbTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sentenceRetire thumb]];

                    //NSLog(@"About to delete these files: %@, %@", imageTrash, thumbTrash);

                    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:imageTrash error:NULL];
                    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:thumbTrash error:NULL];

                //Pop back. 
                    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {      
                        NSLog(@"last sentence in story - delete that story and point, somewhere!");
                        //probably delete the sentece to clear the table, then delete the story using storyRetire

                    } else{
                        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                    }
            }

        }else{
        //  NO: Delete the Sentence Object. 
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            NSString *imageTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString*)[sentenceRetire image]];
            NSString *thumbTrash = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sentenceRetire thumb]];

            //NSLog(@"About to delete these files: %@, %@", imageTrash, thumbTrash);

            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:imageTrash error:NULL];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:thumbTrash error:NULL];

        }


        // Save the context.
        //NSError *error;
        //if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
        //  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //  abort();
        //}

    }

}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (!editing) {
        //save here
        NSError *error;
        BOOL isSaved = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        NSLog(@"isSaved? %@ ======================================", (isSaved ? @"YES" :@"NO ") );
    }
}


// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    //this implementation is from here: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/06/05/re-ordering-nsfetchedresultscontroller/

    NSMutableArray *things = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving.
    NSManagedObject *thing = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [things removeObject:thing];
    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.


    int i = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
    {
        [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"order"];
    }


    NSLog(@"things: %@", things);
    [things release], things = nil; 

    //reordering = YES;
    //NSLog(@"moveRowAtIndexPath: IS reordering");
    //NSError *error;  
    //[managedObjectContext save:&error];   




}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate
/**
 Delegate methods of NSFetchedResultsController to respond to additions, removals and so on.
 */

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    NSLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent: BeginUpdates");

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    beginUpdatesCount++;
    NSLog(@"====================beginUpdates was just incremented");
    NSLog(@"beginUpdatesCount %d", beginUpdatesCount);
    NSLog(@"endUpdatesCount   %d", endUpdatesCount);

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    NSLog(@"didChangeObject: %@", anObject);

    UITableView *tableView;
    tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"ResultsChangeInsert:");
            insert = YES;
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"ResultsChangeDelete:");
            delete = YES;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            NSLog(@"ResultsChangeMove:");
            move = YES;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"switch problem - default");
    }

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    NSLog(@"didChangeSection:");
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    NSLog(@"didChangeContent");
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    NSLog(@"almost endUpdates==============================================");
    if(delete){
        NSLog(@"endUpdates delete");
        delete = NO;
    }
    if(move){
        NSLog(@"endUpdates move");
        move = NO;
    }
    if(insert){
        NSLog(@"endUpdates insert");
        insert = NO;
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    endUpdatesCount++;

    NSLog(@"====================endUpdates was just incremented");
    NSLog(@"endUpdatesCount   %d", endUpdatesCount);
    NSLog(@"beginUpdatesCount %d", beginUpdatesCount);

    NSLog(@"endUpdates finished");

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc Sentence");
    //[fliteEngine stopTalking];
    //[fliteEngine release];
    addButtonItem   = nil;
    playButtonItem  = nil;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { 
        //It doesn't seem to get allocated because it's not set on the iPhone. 
        [addButtonItem  release];
        [playButtonItem release];
    }

    [story release];
    [fetchedResultsController release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: That error says that you deleted a row but that your data source still reports the same number of rows (when it should be one less since you deleted the row).  It looks like you will have this problem whenever sentenceRetire.order is zero since you never remove the object from the data source (but you do otherwise).

Comment: Can you upload your entire project for us to look at?

Comment: I'd rather not upload my whole project - what parts do you need? I've tried to include all the relevant parts of code to this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it would be a lot easier to be able to run this and see it in the debugger....

Comment: Yeah I agree - but it's not something I'm comfortable with. I have dumped the whole UITableViewController in there for now if that's helpful, but I appreciate it is really hard to debug without the project.

Comment: Only if I helped to lead you to the answer.  Otherwise, just add and accept your own answer so that others can see the correct one.  Thank you though!

Comment: That's great that you figured it out, this one has been a tough one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 18/3 #3 I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3267011/459116) about a fetchedResultsController needing to have its delegate set to nil before creating a new one. I put

```
detailViewController.fetchedResultsController = nil;
detailViewController.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
```

in the SVC master view on didselectrowatindexpath and the problem has stopped. RefreshTables created a new fetchedResultsController every time a row was selected in the master view, and I think they were still interfering even when a new story object was selected.

Answer (score 3):

You missed implementing NSFetchedResultsChangeMove in  didChangeObject:

Here is my code which does the same thing:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
  sectionHeadersChanged=NO;
  [self._tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

  switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
      [self._tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
      [self._tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      break;

  }
  sectionHeadersChanged=YES;

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

  UITableView *tableView = self._tableView;

  switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
      [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
      [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
      break;
  }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
  [self._tableView endUpdates];

  //reload all sections
  if(sectionHeadersChanged==YES){
    [self._tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self._tableView.numberOfSections)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I implemented the code as you suggested (I had rem'd it out for some reason) and everything works fine for a few sorts / moves until it freezes and reordering is set to NO. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope - your help fixed moving rows, but I can't consistently add or delete them. Deletion & adding a new item seems intermittently buggy - with either a CoreData exception or just a straight freeze. Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this for: case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.mainTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;